# In JSP retrieving the resources Value by passing key using the getResource and getConfiguration method of Localization

Tags: 2013-sp1, dxa, dxa-1.5

How can I retrieve the values in JSP by passing the key for localization. I can see the `core.json` file under the publication where the key/value pair is defined.

I am using the method `getResource` and `getConfiguration` of `Localization` like

```
localization.getResource("core.keyName")
```

but not getting any value. I have configured Publication in `cd_dynamic` xml file and added the path like `/app/dm/` Is any other configuration required?

```
<jsp:useBean id="markup" 
             type="com.sdl.webapp.common.markup.Markup" scope="request" />
<jsp:useBean id="localization" 
             type="com.sdl.webapp.common.api.localization.Localization" scope="request" />
<jsp:useBean id="pageModel" 
             type="com.sdl.webapp.common.api.model.PageModel" scope="request" />

<%
    String specialOfferText1  = localization.getConfiguration("core.ccSpecialOfferText");  
    System.out.println("Special Offer for Localization ::: "+localization.getId());
    request.setAttribute("specialOfferText", specialOfferText1);
    System.out.println("Special Offer for Localization ::: "
                                              +request.getAttribute("specialOfferText"));

    pageContext.setAttribute("specialOfferText",specialOfferText1);
%>
```

Comment: Can you show your View code which is trying to access configuration?

Comment: View code looks alright. What about the CM-side? Did you put your configuration in the Core config Component? Did you publish the `Publish Settings` Page? Dou you see your config setting in you Web App in `BinaryData/{pubid}/system/config/core.json`?